# mysql Script. Syntax error, Unexpected IDENT_QUOTED errors message on keyword GENERATED

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to open a script in my workbench but the keyword GENERATED is being underlined in red with an error message saying : ` Syntax error, Unexpected IDENT_QUOTED.
This is just a simple DB script.

```
DROP TABLE Addresses;

    CREATE TABLE Addresses
    (
        AddressID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
        FirstName VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
        LastName VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
        Email VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
        PhoneNumber VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL
    );
    INSERT INTO Addresses (FirstName,LastName,Email,PhoneNumber)
        VALUES ('Mike','Green','demo1@deitel.com','555-5555'),
        ('Mary','Brown','demo2@deitel.com','555-1234');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant

```
CREATE TABLE Addresses
(
    AddressID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FirstName VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(AddressID)
);
```

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e20a/1)

Answer (score 0):

MySql does not follow all the Standard SQL syntax:

You need to use `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`

See below example:

```
CREATE TABLE Addresses
    (
        AddressID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        FirstName VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
        LastName VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
        Email VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
        PhoneNumber VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try with this it will not generate error and your table will be created.

```
AddressID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

and last `PRIMARY KEY(AddressID)`